# what does "echo $line" mean in bash？

Tags: linux, bash

What does `echo $line` mean in bash？
I am searching for a long time on net but I could not find anything.

I executed this command and get nothing.

Comment: Anything enclosed in double-quotes is a _string_.  So `"echo $line"` is a string, where the contents of the variable named `line` will be expanded in place of the part of the string containing `$line`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$line` is a shell variable. You get nothing because in you shell `$line` is undefined. But if you will execute echo in environment where `$line` is defined, you will see value of `$line`. For example, you can run those commands:

```
line=123
echo $line
```

In first line you defined variable line. In second line you `echo`ed it. You can learn more about it [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/442332/how-to-work-with-variables-in-bash/)

Comment: I understand, thank you very much

Comment: @q57259028 if my answer solved your question, please, press green checkmark near it :)